# Showing a loading image while during execution of JS function

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing an jQuery mobile application where there is a list menu, When a menu item is getting clicked I am rendering some content in my main UL,

I want to show a loading image or some kind of progress bar till the function gets executed which loads the data into main dTiv.

I tried following but it is not working

```
// my function 
$('ul#playListUl').on('click', 'li', function(evt) {

$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="../../css/images/ajax-loader.gif" />Loading PlayList...</h1>' });  // Not working     

/*
Lot of Business logic goes here, But no ajax calls
I am loading data from localStorage and creating LI elements dynamically
and populating it into the main UL
*/ 

 $.unblockUI(); // Not working
```

Another thing which I tried is

```
$.mobile.loading('show'); at the very beginning of the above function and
$.mobile.loading('hide'); at the end of the above function.
```

But this is also not working

I am using following js version in my code

jQuery mobile 1.3.2
jQuery 1.9.0

Here is my code with Omar your suggestion but still it is not working.

```
    $('ul#playListUl').on('click', 'li', function(evt) {

    // $.mobile.loading('show');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.loading("show", {
            text: "loading videos..",
            textVisible: true
        });
    }, 250);

    //var current = evt.currentTarget;
    var $li = $(this);  
    //console.log(" current target :: "+$(current));
    console.log(" this :: "+$li.attr("data-vmapp-val"));
    // clear the contents
    $videoContainer = $("ul#video-list");
    $videoContainer.html("");

    // first check if the li elements list in localstorage, if yes pull it from there.
    var liElementList = localStorage.getObj($.trim($li.attr("data-vmapp-val")));

    var myPlayList = localStorage.getObj('myPlayList');
    var favouritePlayList = localStorage.getObj('favouritePlayList');

    if (liElementList) {
        $videoContainer.html(liElementList);
        var liElementList = $videoContainer.find('li');
        _.each(liElementList, function(element, index, list) {
            var $liElement = $(element);
            var videoId = $liElement.attr('data-video-id');
            // if the element is in favourite playlist then select it
            if (_.indexOf(favouritePlayList, videoId) != -1) {
                $liElement.find('a.starButton').addClass('starSelected');
                //.remove();
            }
            if (_.indexOf(myPlayList, videoId) != -1) {
                $liElement.find('a.addButton').addClass('plusAdded');
                //.remove();
            }
        });
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    } else {
        var videoListMap = localStorage.getObj('videoListService');
        var videoIdListVal = videoListMap[$.trim($li.attr("data-vmapp-val"))].videoIdList;
        /*
         * <li>
         *      <img>
         *      <div1><info>
         *      <div2><a>
         * </li>
         * "avg_rating": " 3.21",
          "likes": " 480",
          "dislikes": " 389",
          "total_views": "348531",
          "title": "Go Diego Go! English Episode for Children - 2013 (Dora the Explorer Friend)",
          "thumbnail": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9-4ki20O6DI/default.jpg"
         * */
        var videoIdBasedMap = localStorage.getObj("videoIdBasedMap");

        $videoContainer = populateVideoContents(videoIdListVal, videoIdBasedMap, null, favouritePlayList, myPlayList);          
        // store the li list in localstorage
        localStorage.setObj($.trim($li.attr("data-vmapp-val")),  $videoContainer.html());
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }
    // console.log("video UL :: "+$videoContent.html());
    // refresh the UL
    $videoContainer.listview("refresh");

    // refresh the control group div
    $("#demo-page").trigger("create");
    $('div#headerDiv').find('h1').html("Showing Videos from PlayList");
    $('div#headerDiv').find('h1').attr("data-playlist-name", "");

});
```

Comment: Is handling this on the native layer an option?

Comment: When are you calling your fucntion?

Comment: @Ali - I want to do this on client side only, My application is a simple HTML5 application with very less dependency on my android server code apart from loading my single page.

Comment: @Omar - I did not get your question but will try to answer it, I am calling this function when the page is get loaded i.e. pageinit

Comment: If you're using `pageinit` to call it, you need to `setTimeout` to show the loading spinner.

Comment: @omar - is not there any other alternative? If no then a code snippet will help me to understand what needs to be done

Comment: here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7pNAK/ go to gallery page to see the loader.

Comment: @Omar Its not working for me :(

Comment: @Omar Adding my code to the original post

Comment: 250ms delay is too much, reduce it to 50 or so. Are you using `pageinit` to fire the function?

Comment: I tried with 50 but not working, Yes I am calling this function inside paginit